# fasterxml jackson create nested xml using Pojo

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pojo

I want to create xml like below:

```
<color>black</color>
<size>
<height>1</height>
</size>
```

My Pojo class is :

```
public class features {
    private String color;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "size")
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Height height;
    //getter, setter, toString

    class Height{
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="height")
        public String value;  
        //getter, setter, toString
    }
}
```

Json I am passing is :
{
color:"black",
"value":1
}

Output I am getting is :

```
<color>black</color>
<size>
<height/>
</size>
```

why is it not setting value to height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that Jackson can only work with static inner classes. [More info](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html)

Something like this should work

```
static class Height{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="height")
    public String value;

    public Height() {}

    public Height(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

---

Other option is to use correct setter in Features class like

```
@JsonProperty("value")
public void setHeightFromString(String height){
    this.height = new Height();
    this.height.value = height;
}
```

PS: And i assume that your json is valid and looks like  `{ "color":"black", "value":"1" }`